# Authentication for REST API's

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, authentication, https

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTTP Digest Authentication versus SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599048/http-digest-authentication-versus-ssl)

I am using REST Controller in CodeIgnitor to implement a REST Api. I wanted to know if basic authentication over https will be good enough or should I go for digest. I'm also thinking that digest takes more time to process, But still safety is more important.

Please also kindly let me know what are API keys, and how can I use them to add an extra layer of safety.